# How to pass array of strings to a function in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, function

I am noob and I want to pass pointer of an array of strings to a function and that function simply prints the strings of the array using pointer arithmetic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char words[][10] = { "madam", "Russia", "India", "Japan", "China", "Brazil", "Mexico" };
int size = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]);

void printer(char *, int);

int main() {
    printer(*words, size);

    return 0;
}

void printer(char *array, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", (array + i));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
madam
adam 
dam  
am   
m
```

It is not printing elements (strings) one by one.

Comment: Funny question. When you tried that, you must have written a function `main()` (well, you didn't)  that does exactly what you want - Why did you try something different in your `printer` function?

Comment: The `words`, do you need it to be array of arrays of 10 characters which is what you have now (can fit 9 character string)? Or would you be find with array of pointer to const char (which can be string literal), that is `const char *words[] = { ... };`?

Answer (score 2):

As coded, `printer` takes a string and prints every final substring. You pass `*words`, which is the same as `words[0]`, ie: the first string in the 2D array.

To pass a pointer to the array, the type of the argument should be `char array[][10]`<sup>(*)</sup>.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char words[][10] = { "madam", "Russia", "India", "Japan", 
                     "China", "Brazil", "Mexico" };
int size = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]);

void printer(char words[][10], int len);

int main() {
    printer(words, size);
    return 0;
}

void printer(char words[][10], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]));
    }
}
```

Note however that you could also define `array` as an array of pointers to character strings `char *array[]`. This would allow for strings of any length, not limited to 9 characters plus a null terminator.

The code would be changed to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *words[] = { "madam", "Russia", "India", "Japan", 
                  "China", "Brazil", "Mexico" };
int size = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]);

void printer(char *words[], int len);

int main() {
    printer(words, size);
    return 0;
}

void printer(char *words[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]));
    }
}
```

The array `words` is initialized from string literals, which must not be changed, so it would be better to define it as `const char *array[]` and modify `printer` accordingly.  Note also that `printf("%s\n", array[i]))` is equivalent to `puts(array[i])` (good compilers detect this equivalence and generate the call to `puts` in both cases):

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *words[] = { "madam", "Russia", "India", "Japan", 
                        "China", "Brazil", "Mexico" };
int size = sizeof(words) / sizeof(words[0]);

void printer(const char *words[], int len);

int main() {
    printer(words, size);
    return 0;
}

void printer(const char *words[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        puts(array[i]);
    }
}
```

---

<sup>(*)  The function does not receive an actual 2D array as argument, but a pointer to the array of arrays, which technically has type `char (*)[10]` but the compiler will accept both syntaxes equivalently and `char array[][10]` is simpler and more readable</sup>

Comment: This is a bit dangerous, because you have array of pointers to non-const char, but they point to string literals, which normally are in read-only memory segment. It'd be better to have `const char *words[] = { ... };`

Answer (score 1):

You are just printing the 1st element of `words[0]`, because you have passed `words[0]` which is equivalent to `*words`.

Also, to print the whole array of pointers, you need `char [][10]` as your parameter in function `printer()`.

*Note: You can put `printer()` function above `main()` function, then there will be no need for forward declaration.*

##### Final Code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

char words[][10] = {"madam", "Russia", "India", "Japan", "China", "Brazil", "Mexico"};
int size = sizeof(words) / sizeof(*words);

void printer(const char array[][10], int len){
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        puts(array[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printer(words, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Your variable words is an array of pointer.* Not at all: `array` is an array of arrays of 10 bytes.

Comment: `size_t` is not necessarily `unsigned long`. As a matter of fact it is `unsigned int` on most 32-bit systems and `unsigned long long` on 64-bit windows. Avoid confusing newbies with such fallacies. While `size_t` is indeed the *correct* type for indices, using `int` is no problem for most arrays, only huge ones require `size_t`.

Comment: indeed `unsigned long` on 64-bit linux, but not every machine is a linux PC :)

Answer (score -2):

`char *array` to `char (*array)[10]`

Comment: Please explain why the first idiom is not correct.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.